# How to design GUI for my embedded design

Tags: c, embedded, interface

I have designed my embedded software and it is working fine. I was thinking about making good GUI so that it is easy for others to interface with my software.

Comment: What is your development platform, Windows or Linux? I have used embedded QT. [Accelerometer Application on Embedded Linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bd7ULY1frA4)

Comment: which programming language you have used in embedded qt. I am interested in QT but dont know how to set it up for my project. I am comfortable in both windows and linux but if you can tell me how to setup embedded qt for windows then it will be great.

Comment: I have only setup embedded QT for linux. I used 'C'. QT is an IDE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depend on which operating system you are using.

If you are on linux, i would recommend you using gtk/glade.

1. Install GCC and other basic requirement,then install GTK library
2. Install Glade in your system which is used to make UI interface
3. Choose you IDE, like eclipse is best in this case. Add path to your gtk libraries in eclipse
4. Make UI in glade and then program it using gtk libraries in eclipse.

This is all you require to build a professional level GUI in linux for your embedded design.

If you are in windows , I would say go for visual studio . It is best and provides many functionality.

Comment: Great can you give a link to any tutorial for gtk/glade